# problemas al compilar proyecto android en ionic

Tags: ionic

tengo un proyecto creado en ionic, el cual al momento de compilar me da el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentando de todo, desintalando e instalando todo nuevamente, pero nada resulta.

Comment: Hola Elsa, ahora agrego una respuesta, sin embargo te sugiero trates de agrega como texto y no como imagen los mensajes de error en tus preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las situaciones por la cual el proceso DAEMON no puede ejecutarse es precisamente lo que se muestra en el mensaje, memoria para que pueda funcionar correctamente la VM.

> Error ocurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for ... object heap

En este caso tienes que incrementar la memoria, lo puedes realizar dentro de tu archivo **`gradle.properties`**, agrega:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

---

Precisamente en el forum de Ionic existe un thread relacionado a este problema:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/run-android-errors/25128